# html form fade with more than one form

Tags: jquery, html, fade

As you guys know, the .fadeOut and .fadeIn command can be used to fade various elements in and out. My problem is that I have multiple forms and unlike paragraphs whose tags can be made unique through incrementation all forms have the exact same tag. I want to fade out 1 or more forms while leaving the others intact. What can I do? Can I create a custom form tag? Is there a fade command that allows the user to specify the id of the element?

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").fadeOut()
    $("form1").fadeOut()
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("p").fadeIn();
    document.getElementById("form").fadeOut()
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id=form1>
<input id="check1" type="checkbox" />Print Design

</form>

<form id=form2>

<input id="check3" type="checkbox" />Web Design
</form>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in</button>

</body>
</html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_fadeout_fadein

Paste the above code into the compiler at w3schools. You will find that simply putting the ID number in as the argument  does not work. This is because the command is expecting a kind of tag like the

tag.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: you can give forms unique id and fade them using the id.

Comment: @palerdot
how do I use the fade command using id? I tried that and it does not work.

Comment: @brbcoding please see the code that I added

Comment: @jizcoBorneo: look at the answer I posted. You have to use '#' to specify and id. Also, you cannot use jQuery methods like 'fadeIn()' if you select them using pure javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fadeIn and fadeOut would work with any selectors

```
$('#ID').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete
      });
```

Comment: WOOPS! I am missing the # in my argument

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for specifying the id is to add a **#** before the id name.

In your case, the id name is `form1`, so you should be doing

```
$('#form1').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, why separate fadeIn/Out? Use .fadeToggle().